# What is the proper way to reference shared library plugins with dlopen()?

Tags: c++, plugins, shared-libraries, ubuntu-16.04, dlopen

I've got a project, called Super in this hypothetical example, with a set of `.so` files that are built into `/home/whatever/super/`. At runtime, a specification configuration file tells Super which plugins to load using their `.so` name. This is on Ubuntu 16.04.

Example plugins:

- `/home/whatever/super/magic.so`
- `/home/whatever/super/wow.so`
- `/home/whatever/super/awesome.so`

I've set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/whatever/super
```

Within Super, I load the modules using `dlopen()`:

```
std::string filename = "magic.so"
dlopen(filename.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY)
```

At this point, everything works. Now I'm trying to package my project and that means moving things to the correct system directories. I've now switched to using `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/super/` as the base path of the plugins, like so:

- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/super/magic.so`
- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/super/wow.so`
- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/super/awesome.so`

I've also cleared `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I updated the `dlopen()` code to look like this:

```
std::string filename = "super/magic.so"
dlopen(filename.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY)
```

Unfortunately, the system won't load my module. I get this error:

```
Cannot load library: super/magic.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I confirmed that `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` exists and contains:

```
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

What am I doing wrong? I've confirmed that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/super/magic.so` exists. Why is the loader not searching for the `.so` file in that subdirectory of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`? I obviously don't want to hard-code the full paths of the `.so` files into my C++ code.

Finally, is this a good approach for where to put the plugins and the loading approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the common approach is to encode the full paths to the plugin directory (or the plugin `.so` files themselves), then store that path either at compile-time or runtime, rather than relying on the LD components to find the subdirectory.

### Compile-Time

You can use the CMake process to determine the installation directory of the plugin modules, and write that directory into a file prior to compilation, as in [Remmina](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/blob/master/config.h.in):

Line within `config.h.in`:

```
#define REMMINA_PLUGINDIR   "${REMMINA_PLUGINDIR}"
```

Lines within `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if(NOT REMMINA_PLUGINDIR)
    set(REMMINA_PLUGINDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}/remmina/plugins")
endif()

configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h)
```

### Runtime

For a runtime solution, CMake can write the installation path into a config file that is installed along with the software. For example:

Line within `super.conf.in`:

```
PLUGIN_PATH "@SUPER_PLUGINDIR@"
```

Lines within `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if(NOT SUPER_PLUGINDIR)
    set(SUPER_PLUGINDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}/super")
endif()

configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/super.conf.in
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/super.conf
@ONLY)

install(
    FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/super.conf
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
)
```

On my Ubuntu 16.04 system, `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` is an alias for `lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR` is an alias for `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` when creating a package that installs at the system root.

Either way, you can then build a full path with `dlopen` that doesn't require an LD search. Just concatenate the configured string to the plugin filename. The two CMake variable substitution approaches are not critical. I just threw in the `${}` and `@@` alternatives for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid Glibc will not handle relative file paths in `dlopen` (and probly other functions). [Here](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/master/elf/dl-load.c#L2021) you can see that *any* slash causes it to treat filename as absolute and this not search it in standard paths).

I think the best solution would be to pass absolute plugin path to `dlopen`. Might also ask Glibc maintainers for better diagnostics for this type of error.

Comment: Yeah, I have also come to that conclusion. Any insight on the proper plugin approach? I see several official packages that put their plugins into subdirs of the shared library folder.

Comment: @EthanT You could use linker's `-rpath` option to point to plugin dir. Furthermore, if this dir is relative to main executable, you can use `$ORIGIN` to specify relative path.